# How can I initialize object array in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I made object class array like this:

```
private val stockList= MutableList(50){Stock()}
```

Stock class has some variables like `name`, `number`, `price`, etc.
So how do I initialize this object class list?

```
    stoke *item = new stoke[numb];
    for (int a = 0; a < numb; a++) {
        char* tmp = new char[100];
        int price = 0, number = 0;
        cout << a + 1 << ". name price number (using spacebar)";
        cin >> tmp >> price >> number;
        item[a].setproduct(tmp, price, number);

    }
```

When I used c++, I get class member vlaue this way(consol).

```
        val editTitle = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTitle) as EditText
        val editNumber = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editnumber) as EditText
        val editBuy = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editbuy) as EditText
        val editSell = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editsell) as EditText
```

Following is stock class

```
    class stock{
    var name:String?=null
    var buyprice:Int=0
    var sellprice:Int=0
    var important:Boolean = false
    var number:Int = 0}
```

Should I made class Constructor?

When I get these value using layout Widget `editText`, how can I put these value in `stocklist` object?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your question is, and I don't know about Android. But here's an example constructing a list of objects, reading in values from STDIN:

```kotlin
data class Stock(
    var name: String? = null,
    var price: Int = 0,
    var important: Boolean = false,
    var number: Int = 0
)


fun main() {
    print("How many items? ")
    val itemCount = readLine()!!.toInt()

    val items: List<Stock> = (1..itemCount).map {
        print("$it. name price number (using spacebar): ")
        val (inputName, inputPrice, inputNumber) = readLine()!!.split(' ')
        Stock(
            name = inputName,
            price = inputPrice.toInt(),
            number = inputNumber.toInt(),
        )
    }
    println(items)
}
```

Example session:

```
How many items? 3
1. name price number (using spacebar): a 1 2
2. name price number (using spacebar): b 3 4
3. name price number (using spacebar): c 5 6
[Stock(name=a, price=1, important=false, number=2), Stock(name=b, price=3, important=false, number=4), Stock(name=c, price=5, important=false, number=6)]
```